# Attenuators - volts to microvolts

Tags: attenuator

My DAC gives  +/- 16V analog output voltage and +/- 20mA output current.

- Output impedance in voltage mode: 25 miliohm.
- Output impedance in current mode: 100 megaohm.

I need to design an attenuator for 100 microvolt steps and a signal range of 500mV output.

Voltage range given is +5V  to -5V.
This has to be done from differential ended as well as single ended output from DAC.

Comment: What is your question and please fix the opening line to indicate current and not voltage (+/- 20mV is what you have written and this appears to be an error).

Comment: "*Voltage range given is +5V to -5V.*" What has this got to do with  "*My DAC gives +/- 16V ...*" and "*a signal range of 500mV output*"? Your post is rather confused.

Comment: @Transistor I get confused more each time I read the question.

Comment: What will control the attenuator? According to your numbers, it would need 5000 steps (500mV/100uV). What is the accuracy requirement? As others have noted, you need to clean up your description of your problem and provide much more informaton.

Comment: DAC spec's:
Channels :8 analog o/p channels  Resolution:16bit Type of DAC:R-2R
Update rate :250kS/s /channel timing resolution :10ns

DAC Analog outputs (both Voltage and current modes) with following specifications.

Voltage Mode: Output Voltage range: +/- 16V Current drive : +/- 20mA/channel max output impedance : 20mili Ohm slew rate :+/- 10 V /micro sec

Current Mode:Output current range : +/- 20mA Compliance voltage : +/- 16V /channel max Output impedance : 100Mega Ohm slew rate :+/- 20mA /micro sec

Need to design an attenuator for 100microvolt steps & signal range of 500mV o/p